# Is is possible in C++ to throw nothing?

Tags: c++, exception, destructor, throw

Under exceptional circumstances, I want my program to stop processing, output an error to `std::cerr`, clean up, and exit.

However, calling `exit()` will not call all the destructors of any objects that have been constructed.  I would like to have the destructors called nicely, so I wrapped all the code in a `try-catch` block, something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    try {
        bool something_is_not_right = false;
        /* lots of variables declared here */
        /* some code that might set something_is_not_right to true goes here */
        if(something_is_not_right){
            std::cerr << "something is not right!!!" << std::endl;
            throw '\0';  // dummy unused variable for throwing.
        }
    }
    catch (...) {}
    return 0;
}
```

In this way, I get guaranteed destruction of all my variables.  But I can't seem to find a way to get C++ to `throw` nothing.  `throw;` has a special meaning in C++; it isn't throwing nothing.

Is there a way to `throw` nothing?

Comment: Why do you need to throw nothing, instead of throwing your custom type `abnormal_program_termination`?

Comment: I agree with @SebastianRedl. See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/ and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/throw ... Throw is not intended to be used without an expression, i.e. something you can throw around. You can solidify your code, using custom errors, exceptions or other error-objects...

Comment: If you want full cleanup, then calling `exit()` might not be the right thing to do in the first place.

Comment: @SebastianRedl So it seems the solution is to make something out of nothing.

Comment: You only use `throw;` without anything if you handled an exception in a `catch` block and want to rethrow to the caller.

Comment: @HenriMenke Unless nothing is being handled, then `std::terminate` is called.

Comment: @Bernard Or the solution is to stop thinking about it as throwing nothing, and instead thinking about it as throwing an abnormal program termination error. If it was nothing, you wouldn't need to throw.

Comment: in a very simple (non-recursive) case, simple `return 0` will also call all destructors. If you want the other, just create your own exception class to be handled as termination by abnormal condition.

Comment: Instead of setting `something_is_not_right = true`, why not `throw something_is_not_right`?

Comment: @Snps It feels redundant because `something_is_not_right` is always false when thrown.

Comment: @Bernard Yes but `something_is_not_right` can instead be a `struct something_is_not_right : public std::runtime_error { using std::runtime_error::runtime_error; }`. The point is that you already have some logic that handles an error using a boolean variable. Why not replace setting a `bool` to `true` with throwing an exception? You've already succumbed to using exceptions anyway.

Comment: @Snps the `bool` was just a simple way to illustrate my predicament.

Comment: I think the key insight to this question is this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43675700/is-is-possible-in-c-to-throw-nothing/43676128?#comment74397979_43675700) by @SebastianRedl

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## No

It's not possible to throw nothing. You need to throw *something*. While you may have seen people use the `throw` keyword without anything, this just means they are re-throwing the currently handled exception.

Comment: As mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/43675980/2428220, if you do attempt to throw nothing it will compile but will terminate the program without any stack unwinding being performed.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a personal recommendation.

You might want to take a look at the predefined exceptions of [`stdexcept`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) which cover almost any exceptional behaviour that occurs in a program.  In your case I would throw a [`std::runtime_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error).  Also, only catch what you expect to be thrown and not *catch 'em all*.  If you really want to catch everything, then catch [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) (the base class of all standard exceptions).

In my opinion handling unknown exceptions doesn't really make sense and the only logical consequence is to just abort execution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

int main()
{
  try
  {
    bool something_is_not_right = true;
    if ( something_is_not_right )
      throw std::runtime_error("something is not right!!!");
  }
  catch (std::runtime_error& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a view that I have not heard of before.  While throwing a `runtime_error` would be okay in this question, there might be other things (with additional properties perhaps) that one might need to throw, no?

Comment: @Bernard I think I don't understand your question.  Of course, if you have exceptional behaviour which is not covered by or needs extensions to the standard exceptions like `std::runtime_error`, then you define your own.

Comment: I think I have misunderstood your answer and taken "unknown exceptions doesn't really make sense" to mean "defining your own exceptions doesn't really make sense".

Comment: @Bernard Ah, I see.  Yes, only handle what you expect and what you know.  If you do not expect `std::logic_error` but only `std::invalid_argument`, then you only handle `std::invalid_argument` and leave `std::logic_error` unhandled.

Comment: I think this is the key, only catch what you can handle.  Catching everything is generally (not always) a bad thing.   My goto example for someone catching everything is "how are you going to handle an out of memory exception".  When they say "it's just for logging", my response is "you are out of memory, why do you think the logger will even work in that situation".

Answer (score 3):

Well you "can" but it doesn't throw nothing. It terminates.

> **5.17 Throwing an exception:**
>
> 2. Evaluating a throw-expression with an operand throws an exception (15.1)
> 3. A throw-expression with no operand rethrows the currently handled exception (15.3).
> 4. If no exception is presently being handled, evaluating a throw-expression with no operand calls `std::terminate()`

This is valid:

```
int main () {
  throw;
  return 0;
}
```

Source used: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf

But it won't cleanup anything. `std::terminate` is used when the cleanups fail.

Otherwise you have to use operand, and then this section becomes relevant:

> **15.1 Throwing an exception [except.throw]**
>
> 3. Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object, called the exception object. The temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching handler (15.3).

So you have to pass something that is able to be initialized, which by definition cannot be nothing.

Comment: Only because it is valid does not mean you should do it.  Also the `return 0;` is gratuitous, as the standard guarantees that a `return 0;` is implicitly inserted at the end of `main`.

Comment: This is not useful. The OP wants to know whether it's possible to unwind without an exception object. But "throwing nothing" (a simple `throw;`) looks for a currently-caught exception object and throws that; it doesn't throw nothing.

Comment: @HenriMenke And since it is unreachable code, the compiler may even warn about it.

Comment: "_evaluating a throw-expression with no operand calls `std::terminate()`_" - the default `std::terminate_handler` will call `std::abort` which will _not_ cleanup anything.

Comment: I have added the information that throwing nothing does not perform cleanups. And changed the wording to be clearer.

Comment: @Bernard It may not solve your problem (which seems to be stubbornly not wanting to throw something when you should make something to throw or at least just throw `std::runtime_error`), but it does provide information of what actually happens if you `throw;` "nothing", so it is certainly part of an answer to your question.

Comment: @Bernard It kind of does IMHO. Because if you can't throw "nothing", you have to throw something. It cannot be "void". I have added another reference.

Comment: @luk32 Seems like essentially C++ forbids throwing nothing by design.

Comment: @Bernard Well, there is a syntax for "nothing", but it is used to call a rather abrupt form of termination. And the other one specifically states, there is a temporary object, and that it is an lvalue, which are pretty strongly constituted entities, if one might say so. But I don't see nothing wrong in using some standard exception like `std::runtime_error`, I think closest you can get to nothing is to define an empty class and throw an instance of it. But even then being pedantic it has to have storage, and its `sizeof` is non zero.

Answer (score 3):

How do you know that the reason for the catch is your error or something else (out of memory is always a good one).   If you detect an error, then you should create and throw the reason for that error in a custom exception.  Then in main, you can tell the difference between your detected error and something you didn't expect.  It's just good practice.

Answer (score 2):

In order to ensure full cleanup you have to throw an exception **and catch it somewhere**. Implementations are not required to clean up stack objects when an exception is thrown but not caught. The requirement (in [except.handle]/9) when an exception is thrown but not caught is that the program calls `std::terminate()`, and it's implementation-defined whether stack objects are cleaned up.